# Google charts com código no body para request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-charts

Pessoal alguem já utilizou o goolecharts ? só consigo fazer plotar o grafico se ele está no head, como faço para o código dele ficar no body ? Pois quero plotar via um request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  // Create some random text-encoded data for a line chart.
  header('content-type: image/png');
  $url = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart';
  $chd = 't:';
  for ($i = 0; $i < 150; ++$i) {
    $data = rand(0, 100000);
    $chd .= $data . ',';
  }
  $chd = substr($chd, 0, -1);

  // Add data, chart type, chart size, and scale to params.
  $chart = array(
    'cht' => 'lc',
    'chs' => '600x200',
    'chds' => '0,100000',
    'chd' => $chd);

  // Send the request, and print out the returned bytes.
  $context = stream_context_create(
    array('http' => array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'content' => http_build_query($chart))));
  fpassthru(fopen($url, 'r', false, $context));
?>
```

Comment: <img width='600' height='200' src='chartserver-image.php'> 

é isso que precisa?